# Django channels session issue with Redis as channel layer backend

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I use Django Channels in combination with a seperate Javascript frontend. Websockets work fine. What I now want to do is:

- when user opens website, backend generates a specific id. The backends saves that id in the session with `message.channel_session['my_id']`
- on subsequent calls to the backend via the websocket, I want to retreive that key from the session.

However, sometimes this seems to work, and sometimes I get a `KeyError`; `my_id` does not seem to exist. My code:

`routing.py`:

```
from channels.routing import route
from chat.consumers import ws_connect, ws_receive

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
]
```

And `consumers.py`:

```
import uuid
from channels.sessions import channel_session


@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    message.channel_session['my_id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())

@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    my_id = message.channel_session['my_id']  # this one sometimes fails...
```

However, when I switch channel layer backend from Redis to in-memory, it works fine (I use `./manage.py runserver` so I don't run a seperate worker)

Any ideas? Is there a race condition or something?

Comment: Have you tried making a `websocket_keepalive` consumer?

Comment: did you solved this?